# android studio - dependencies under if condition - flags

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I currently have an add which has some dependencies in the build.gradle

```
dependencies {
     compile project: 'com.name.libOne', name: 'libOne'
     compile group: 'com.name.libTwo', name: 'libTwo'
     //a few more dependencies
    }
```

Now i'm looking for a way to put some dependencies under some condition
so not every time i build the app it will have all of these dependencies.

Like this:

```
dependencies {
     if (one) {
         compile project: 'com.name.libOne', name: 'libOne'
     }
     compile group: 'com.name.libTwo', name: 'libTwo'
     //a few more dependencies
}
```

Is there anyway to do that? So i can send flags to the build command
`gradlew.bat assembleDebug` and the flag will be read by these conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to move specific depencdencies into separete `.gradle` files and apply them conditionally. For example, let's assume, you create a `libOneDependency.gradle` file in the same directory as your current build script and it contains:

```
dependencies {
    compile project: 'com.name.libOne', name: 'libOne'
}
```

Then you apply it into your main build script, out of the `dependencies` closure, as follows

```
if (project.hasProperty('nameOfYourFlag')) 
{
  apply from: 'libOneDependency.gradle'
}
```

So, now you have to provide your flag to the build as `-PnameOfYourFlag`

Comment: where can I apply a flag to the build?

Comment: then you run your build: `gradlew.bat assembleDebug -PnameOfYourFlag`

Comment: It works. Only problem is now that i don't want to use some parts, i get a compilation error. can you think of any solution